# Searching filter value from text

Tags: sql, hana

```
select id,type, Rt_behaviour_text,created_at
from table_name;
```

Here value for the column 'type' is dependant on searching text from 'Rt_behaviour_text' which holds xml data.

If the specific filter value 'type=REALTIME' is available into 'Rt_behaviour_text', then 'type' column would be filled up with 'REALTIME' otherwise ''.

How can I do this in sap hana?

Answer (score 0):

Some more information is missing there.

- How You will insert new values?
- You want to perform this logic during INSERT?
- Or You want to fill type column during SELECT?

There could be different ways to solve this.

Example SELECT statement could look like this:

```
SELECT 
    id,
    CASE     
     WHEN instr(stackoverflow.rt_behaviour_text, 'type=REALTIME') > 0 THEN 'REALTIME'
     ELSE ''
    END AS TYPE,
    rt_behaviour_text
FROM STACKOVERFLOW;
```

int **instr**(string, string)
Returns the position of the first occurrence of the second string within the first string (>= 1) or 0, if the second string is not contained in the first.

[SAP HANA String functions doc](https://help.sap.com/viewer/e8e6c8142e60469bb401de5fdb6f7c00/2.0.05/en-US/f5a9ca3718354a499a98ba61ae3da170.html)

---

Also, You could implement trigger which will run during insert on Your table.

```
 CREATE TRIGGER STACKOVERFLOW_TRIGGER
 BEFORE INSERT ON STACKOVERFLOW 
 REFERENCING NEW ROW NEW      
 FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
     IF instr(:NEW.rt_behaviour_text, 'type=REALTIME') > 0 THEN NEW.type = 'REALTIME';
     ELSE NEW.TYPE = '';
     END IF;
 END;
```

After that, during INSERT

```
INSERT INTO STACKOVERFLOW(TYPE, rt_behaviour_text) VALUES (NULL, '<xml test="test" type=REALTIME>');
```

type column will be updated according to the implemented logic in the trigger.

Comment: For calculations on insert there's another option: calculated column as of at least 1.0 SPS12.

Comment: yes, during insert and data comes from different table for this column.But problem has been solved. thank you